# which class of ODE equations can not be solved theoretically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

which class of ODE equations can not be solved in both real and complex numbers field?

An example with an proof for that example are welcomed

Comment: I'm pretty sure most ODEs can't be solved, as well as most PDEs. All *linear* ODEs are solvable, but many ODEs are not.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I think Victor is referring to existence results. Though you are still right that ODE IVPs can fail to have even a local solution if the right side is not nice enough.

Comment: I believe it is true that an arbitrary ODE is unsolvable almost surely, although I cannot cite that as fact.

Comment: @Arkamis - Is that true that mathematics doesn't have a theory  to address my question already?

Comment: Quite the opposite. It's just that there are infinitely many, and probably uncountably infinitely many, unsolvable differential equations, so trying to enumerate them all is a feeble effort.

Comment: @Arkamis - Are there infinite number of different class that is unsolvable?

Comment: I think you might prefer this question: Does there exist a differential equation $g(f^{(n)},f^{(n-1)},...,f,x)=0$, such that the corresponding equation $g(x_n,x_{n-1},...,x_1,x_0)=0$ has solutions in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, but that itself has no solution?

Comment: @Victor I would conjecture yes.

Comment: @Victor I like your question. If there is a solution, this is how.. if cannot be found, and that's it...you have the numerical solution route anyhow. There is no existence test applicable *any* ODE.

Comment: @Narasimham - Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if one allows complex-valued functions, 
$$ y' = y'+1 $$
Cannot be solved, despite it being an "equation". You need to be more specific what kind equation you are talking about. For example, you can consider DE of the form $y' = f(x,y)$. Those can be solved under suitable conditions. But we had to restrict the class of equations.

Comment: What is some other class of equation that can not be solved?

Comment: @Victor I think the better question to ask is "which class of equations can be solved". A randomly thrown equation, entirely non-linear, with mixed derivatives, all over the place, will most likely not be solvable. So the more appropriate question is to try to find those types of DE that (i) come up in mathematics/physics/whatever and (ii) can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you limit it to real numbers, then there are many ordinary differential equations that cannot be solved.  For example,

$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^2+1=0$

$\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{dx}}\right|+|y|=-1$

Comment: Can you offer an proof?

Comment: Well, for the first to have a solution, the derivative would have to square to $-1$. Can you think of a real number that does that? The second one DOES have a solution, namely $y(x) = 0$, but if you change the right hand side to $-1$, then it does not.

Comment: For the first equation, use the fact that the square of any real number is non-negative.  For the second equation, use the definition of absolute value.